# How do I show the local path in a registered component?

Tags: com, dcom

I use the **/regserver** command switch to register a COM server.  For example:

```
program.exe /regserver
```

But when I look at the registered component in *dcomdnfg*, the local path blank (unavailable).

[image]

How do I show the local path of the registered component in *dcomcfg* ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to view the details of a 32-bit component on a 64-bit operating system? If so, you need to take care to use the correct `dcomcnfg` version: Run `mmc comexp.msc -32` in the command prompt. Then, navigate to the DCOM Config node and select your component. You should now be able to see its path.